# IERC20 balanceOf() function doesn't renew data with every new block

Tags: uniswapv3

I'm trying to get balances of USDC and WETH from Uniswap V3 Pool and USDC/WETH price with every new block. This is my code:

```
async function getPrice(inputTokenA,inputTokenB){
 
  let today = new Date()
  let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  
  pairAddress = "0x8ad599c3A0ff1De082011EFDDc58f1908eb6e6D8"

  // Get ERC20 Token contract instance
  pairAddress = "0x8ad599c3A0ff1De082011EFDDc58f1908eb6e6D8"

  smallToken0 = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20","0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48")
  smallToken1 = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20","0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2")
  let reserve0 = await smallToken0.balanceOf(pairAddress);
  let reserve1 = await smallToken1.balanceOf(pairAddress);
  
  let formattedUSDC = Number(
      ethers.utils.formatUnits(reserve0, 6)
    );
  

  //
 
  const quoterAddress = "0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6";
  const quoterContract = new ethers.Contract(quoterAddress, QuoterABI, provider)
  let quotedAmountOut = 0
  let amtIn = "1"
  let amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amtIn, 18).toString()
  

  try {
    quotedAmountOut = await quoterContract.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle(
      inputTokenA,
      inputTokenB,
      500,
      amountIn,
      0)
  } catch (err) {
    return 0
  }

    // Format Output
    let outputAmount = ethers.utils.formatUnits(quotedAmountOut, 6)
    let outputAmount2 = parseFloat(outputAmount).toFixed(0)
    console.log(  formattedUSDC,reserve1, outputAmount2, time )

async function web(){
  
  web3Ws = new Web3(new
Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/infura"));
      var subscription = web3Ws.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function(error, result){

  })
  .on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
      console.log("ID",subscriptionId);
  })
  .on("data", function(blockHeader){
    getPrice("0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2","0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48")
  
  let today = new Date()

    if (today.getHours()>=18 && today.getMinutes()>=15){
    
    subscription.unsubscribe(function(error, success){
      
      console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
      if(success) return
  })};
  
})
```

}

Everything works, but this is what I get:

```
52244518.857732 BigNumber { value: "95628828301060254089480" } 1279 17:28:20
52244518.857732 BigNumber { value: "95628828301060254089480" } 1278 17:28:25
52244518.857732 BigNumber { value: "95628828301060254089480" } 1278 17:28:37 .....



 52244518.857732 BigNumber { value: "95628828301060254089480" } 1284 17:55:40
 52244518.857732 BigNumber { value: "95628828301060254089480" } 1284 17:55:50
 52244518.857732 BigNumber { value: "95628828301060254089480" } 1284 17:56:2
```

My function doesn't renew balances.
But if I stop and launch it again I receive the new data:

```
54258304.239956 BigNumber { value: "94292726075356721409097" } 1285 17:58:3
```

May be I don't understand totally how this balanceOf() function works or smth wrong with variables so it gives me the same value every block.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my problem with Web3, but if somebody explains me the difference it would be great.

```
const minABI = [
  // balanceOf
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [{ name: "_owner", type: "address" }],
    name: "balanceOf",
    outputs: [{ name: "balance", type: "uint256" }],
    type: "function",
  },
];

const contract0 = new Web3Client.eth.Contract(minABI, tokenAddress0);
const contract1 = new Web3Client.eth.Contract(minABI, tokenAddress1);

const result0 = await contract0.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call(); 
const result1 = await contract1.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();

//result

54053059413821 94590933235733827986206 1283 19:32:19
54053059413821 94590933235733827986206 1283 19:32:19
54297024082418 94401689479863757592814 1287 19:32:19
54297024082418 94401689479863757592814 1287 19:32:19
54297024082418 94401689479863757592814 1287 19:32:19
54533361903385 94218241995364223756593 1288 19:32:19
54573185008937 94187346180895580276213 1288 19:32:19
```